# pyshark Live Capture with wrong display_filter argument

Tags: pyshark

1. I am running live capture with pyshark module:

   ```
   filtered_cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(display_filter='TCPP', only_summaries=True)  
   packet_iter = filtered_cap.sniff_continuously()  
   for pkt in packet_iter:
       print(pkt)
   ```
2. The `display filter` argument is incorrect e.g. `'TCPP'`
3. When running this code I have got exception that I cannot catch.

```
Exception ignored in: <function Capture.____del____ at ...> 
    ...  
pyshark.capture.capture.TSharkCrashException: TShark seems to have crashed (retcode: 2)
```

Any suggestion how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You likely solved this problem already, but this works for me.

```
import pyshark

def filter_tcp_live_packet_capture(network_interface):
    capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=network_interface, display_filter='tcp', only_summaries=True)
    capture.sniff(timeout=50)
    for packet in capture.sniff_continuously(packet_count=5):
        try:
           print(packet)
        except AttributeError as e:
           pass

filter_tcp_live_packet_capture('en0')
```